# Wordpress добавляет лишний символ в заголовке

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress выводит в заголовке лишний символ «ETX». Заголовок выводится стандартной функцией:

```
wp_title()
```

Comment: И? Примеры кода?

Comment: wp_title() - вот и весь пример.

Comment: functions.php смотрели? там переопределения нету? Плагины смотрели? отключали лишние?

Comment: Да, все плагины выключал, functions.php вообще чистый.

Comment: попробуйте отключить javascript и зайти на сайт, добавятся ли к title лишние символы? шаблон я так понимаю бесплатный, скачанный с какого-то сайта? название шаблона можно узнать?

Comment: Все также, шаблон сверстан собственными ручками.

Comment: Что с кодировкой cms, базы данных? Везде utf-8?

Comment: Везде utf-8. В бд все ок, лишнего символа нет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выводить так:

```
$title = wp_title('', false);
$title = preg_replace('/\x03/', '', $title);
echo $title;
```

Answer (score 1):

В стандартный `wp_title()` добавить "" - пустую строку, которая заменит символ, по дефолту добавляемый в заголовок. `true` - выводит содержимое, а не возвращает его в переменную.

```
<?php wp_title("", true); ?>
```